# Linking Shiny Reactive inputs and input updates

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have a dataset of baby names that are ranked by popularity for each year.

What I currently have: a simple shiny app that filters on year based on a slider and a select button that identifies which column is the rank column to use (which also creates a color highlight). This will be two datasets in actuality, one for gender marked as M or gender marked as F, but I've left it simple for the example here.

What I would like to do: update this to be reactive to the values of a slider, which then updates a select option for which file column to sort and highlight.

The current approach works for simplicity, but the focus selector for the year obviously throws an error if it's a value that no longer exists in the slider selected range.

I've dug around and tried a few approaches, but I just haven't been able to get the reactivity portion to work successfully. I'm sure I'm missing something elementary but hitting a wall. Thank you for any input.

Example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

#Fake Data
dat <- structure(list(Name = c("Bill", "Sean", "Kirby", "Philbert", 
  "Bob", "Lucius", "Fry", "Tyron", "Lionel", "Alister", "Newt", 
  "Craig", "A-Aron", "Bill", "Sean", "Kirby", "Philbert", "Bob", 
  "Lucius", "Fry", "Tyron", "Lionel", "Alister", "Newt", "Craig", 
  "A-Aron", "Bill", "Sean", "Kirby", "Philbert", "Bob", "Lucius", 
  "Fry", "Tyron", "Lionel", "Alister", "Newt", "Craig", "A-Aron"
), rank = c(8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 9L, 7L, 25L, 10L, 35L, 
  99L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 11L, 5L, 12L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 
  2L, 3L, 10L, 8L, 11L, 5L, 6L, 12L, 7L, 13L, 9L, 1L), year = c(2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 
    2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 
    2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2009L, 2010L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 2010L, 
    2010L, 2010L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -39L))

#Get years
years <- unique(dat$year)


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Top Ten Male Baby Names"),
  sliderInput("range",
    label = "Choose year range",
    min = min(as.numeric(years)),
    max = max(as.numeric(years)),
    sep = "",
    value = c(max(as.numeric(years))-1,max(as.numeric(years)))
  ),
  
  selectInput("year", 
    label = "Choose year for rank",
    choices = as.numeric(years),
    selected = max(as.numeric(years))
  )
  ,
  
  mainPanel(
    dataTableOutput("DataTable")
  )
  
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$DataTable <- renderDataTable({
    dat1 <- dat %>%
      filter((year >= input$range[1] & year <= input$range[2]) ) %>%
      pivot_wider(id_cols = Name,
        values_from = rank,
        names_from = year) %>%
      filter(.[colnames(.) == as.character(input$year)] <11) %>%
      arrange(.[colnames(.)== as.character(input$year)])
    
    datatable(dat1,
      options = list(ordering=F,
        lengthChange = F,
        pageLength = -1)) %>%
      formatStyle(input$year,
        backgroundColor = "lightgreen"
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set up an observeEvent to watch for changes to the sliderInput. Then if your select input is not in the range of the slider. Update the selection.

Note: you need to add the session param to the server function.

Also since `output$DataTable` is filtered by the range and the year. I've added a validate statement incase the user were to manually chose a year that is not in the current range.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # Observe for a change to slider input
  observeEvent(input$range, {
    sel = input$year
    # update selection if original selected year is not in range
    if(!(sel %in% input$range)) {
      sel = min(input$range)
      
      updateSelectInput(session, "year", selected = sel)
    }
  })
  
  output$DataTable <- renderDataTable({
    validate(need(input$year %in% input$range,"Current selection not in range"))

    dat1 <- dat %>%
      filter((year >= input$range[1] & year <= input$range[2]) ) %>%
      pivot_wider(id_cols = Name,
        values_from = rank,
        names_from = year) %>%
      filter(.[colnames(.) == as.character(input$year)] <11) %>%
      arrange(.[colnames(.)== as.character(input$year)])
    
    datatable(dat1,
      options = list(ordering=F,
        lengthChange = F,
        pageLength = -1)) %>%
      formatStyle(input$year,
        backgroundColor = "lightgreen"
      )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a go when I'm back at my desk next week to see if it does what I need.

Comment: Okay. Finally back at my desk.  This almost did what I needed. Because range is a beginning point and an end point, the validate was incorrectly throwing a message for the between values. The following seemed to address the issue: validate(need(input$year %in% seq(input$range[1], input$range[2], by =1),"Current selection not in range")).

Comment: Ah right, my mistake on that. Glad you got that sorted!